# Access argument data in Kotlin from Flutter's Method channel

Tags: android, json, kotlin, flutter, dart

I have setup a basic Method channel in flutter and Kotlin.

Following is my sample data:

```
{    
    "user_dob":"15 November 1997", 
    "user_description":"Hello there, I am a User!", 
    "user_gender":"Male", 
    "user_session":"KKDSH3G9OJKJFIHXLJXUGWIOG9UJKLJ98WHIJ"
}
```

Following method channel can pass the data to Kotlin side from Flutter:

```
var result = await platform.invokeMethod('updateProfile', data);
```

Following code catches the data in Kotlin:

```
MethodChannel(flutterView, channel).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
      if(call.method == "updateProfile"){
        var argData = call.arguments
...
```

Now,`argData` contains the data I just sent,
and two questions come up:

1. How do I access data from `argdata`? for.eg.
2. How do I get my `user_dob` from this `argData`?

Following code is my current solution.

```
val userDOB : String = call.argument("user_dob")
```

But the following error is thrown: `Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected`

> Note: When I was sending the map data to the MethodChannel, it was accidentally being sent as a String. To follow **THIS** method through, please make sure that a Map object is implemented in passing the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When getting method argument from method channel of Flutter the data that comes in, is a json formatted String.

You can simply call `call.argument`, and it will return a **Nullable** string.

In your case you requested for a `String` which in Kotlin is `Nun-null` String object, but the returned value of `call.argument` might not exists in the json and be null. So you must get a `String?` instead which is a `Nullable` String.

**Update**

Check and make sure channel is able to pass data to the native.

In flutter:

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('NAME');
```

And in native code:

```
val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "NAME");
```

**TL; DR**

In Kotlin use **Nullable object** for data that can be null.

```
val userDOB : String? = call.argument("user_dob")
```

And use it with `?.` (Null safe)

Comment: I tried using the first one and it compiled. But when I tried using the method call, I got type cast errors. 
`java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Make sure channel is intact, and also since argument returns a `T`, you should specify the type.

Comment: also, what do you mean, the argument returns a T. How do I specify a type? I am new to Kotlin

Comment: The type you specify to the `val` will cast the generic `T`. So `val user: String? = call.argument()` will cast the `T` to `String?`

Comment: ok, so the issue I had, was that I was not sending a map data object. What I was sending was a String. So, I then created a Map() object and then sent it over the method channel. Then following your solution and casting with String?, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Map Json:

```json
{    
    "user_dob":"15 November 1991", 

}
```

Kotlin Code：

```kotlin
MethodChannel(flutterView, channel).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
    //you can get data in this object.
    val user_dob = call.argument<String>("user_dob")
    if (user_dob == null) {
       // error
       result.notImplemented()
       return@setMethodCallHandler
    }

    //do else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pass arguments in EventChannel**

cast arguments to *HashMap<String, String>*

Json String

```
{'ip': '192.168.43.8','port':'812','timeout':500,"porta":[10,80]}
```

1. Kotlin

```
 portbyipchannel =
        EventChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "portbyIpchanne")
    portbyipchannel.setStreamHandler(object : EventChannel.StreamHandler {

        override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
            val hashMap = arguments as HashMap
            val port = hashMap["port"]
            val ip = hashMap["ip"]
            val timeout = hashMap["timeout"]
            val arrayList = hashMap["porta"] as ArrayList
            val from = arrayList.get(0) as Int
            val to = arrayList.get(1) as Int

        }

        override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
            print("=========>$arguments")
        }

    })
```

2. Dart

```js
static const EventChannel portbyIp_channel =
  const EventChannel('portbyIpchannel');
  Stream<String>? _onportbyIp;
Stream<String>? get onPortbyIp {
    var arguments = {
      'ip': '192.168.43.8',
      'port': '812',
      'timeout': 500,
      "porta": [10, 80]
    };
    _onportbyIp = portbyIp_channel
        .receiveBroadcastStream(arguments)
        .map((event) => event.toString());
    return _onportbyIp;
  }
```

[image]

**Pass arguments in MethodChannel**

1. Dart

```js
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('android_ip');
  static Future<String?> get IpAddress_Wifi_tetherorwifi async {
    final String? version =
        await _channel.invokeMethod('Wifi_tetherorWifi', {'ip': '192.168.43.8',
          'port': '812',
          'timeout': 500,
          "porta": [10, 80],'key': 'true'});
    return version;
  }
```

2.Kotlin

```
when (call.method) {
"Wifi_tetherorWifi"->result.success(setMyMethod(call.arguments arguments as HashMap))
}
```

[image]